# Display large multi-line HTML content in ASP.NET

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, asp-classic

In Classic ASP,
I can easily display HTML content like this:

```
    <% if a=b then %>
    <div>line 1 (a static content1 here)</div>
    <div>line 2 (a static content2 here)div>
    <div>line 3 (a static content3 here)</div>
    <div>... (more than 10000 lines, no problem)</div>
    <% end if %>
```

But how can I do it easily in ASP.NET ?

I can write some line by using Response.Writeline

```
Response.writeLine("<div>Line 1</div>")
Response.writeLine("<div>Line 2</div>")
Response.writeLine("<div>Line 3</div>")
....
```

But that's so hard to display large content

Comment: Are you using a restful service? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBScript and vb.net are different languages, but they have similar syntax, so your very simple example above should actually work with VB.net.  One thing you need to bear in mind though is that with VB.net is that `Option Explicit` is on by default and therefore you must declare your variables.  (It's good practice to turn it on in Classic ASP VBScript).  The following would certainly work

```
<% Dim a As String, b As String
        a = "ABCD"
        b = "ABCD"
        If a = b Then
%>
     <p> Your 10000 lines of code here</p>

<% End If %>
```

However, while there's nothing to stop you from using Classic asp style scriptlets in .aspx files, ASP.net offers nicer options.  I suggest you look at the `<asp:Literal>` control, eg:

```
<asp:Literal ID = "EFGH" runat="server" Visible="false">
Your 10000 lines of code
</asp:Literal>
```

And then in the codebehind you could use

```
Dim a As String, b As String
    a = "ABCD"
    b = "ABCD"

    If a = b Then
        EFGH.Visible = true
    End If
```

So that the codebehind changes the `Visible` property of the control

Comment: I'd actually recomend `asp:Panel` instead of literal here.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it's not the best idea to be writing HTML content out to your pages from code-behind.  Too many chances for mismatched HTML tags, etc.

That being said, if you want to do it... there are several choices.

The  tag.  This would let you add some HTML (or raw content) into the page, via that literal tag.  This is quite handy if you want to render HTML that comes from a Database or from a web service.

If you just want to hide/show things, then wrapping your HTML in an asp:panel tag is a good idea.  Then you get all the HTML syntax checking from Visual Studio, and you just show/hide that panel as needed.